# Bind to a property's property

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I have a `List (Of MyObject)` binding to a GridView in the `Page_Load` event. `MyObject` has a child object as a property, `ChildObject` which also has a property itself, `ChildProperty`.

In my GridView, I would like to bind one of the fields to `ChildProperty`, but doing something like:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="ChildObject.ChildProperty" />
```

results in an error:

> System.Web.HttpException: A field or property with the name 'ChildObject.ChildProperty' was not found on the selected data source.

How do I bind to that property, or is it not possible? I suppose I could create a ReadOnly property in my parent object just to read the child property, but that's a bit smelly.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: How do you bind a gridview column to a subclass value? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627996/how-do-you-bind-a-gridview-column-to-a-subclass-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Property.ChildProperty.GrandChildProperty") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: ah, true. was hoping for an easier way, but this definitely works

Answer (score -1):

In an ItemTemplate I would use:

```
<%# (Eval("ChildObject") as objectType).ChildProperty #>
```